# Input text onkeyup ajax insert to mysql

Tags: mysql, ajax, forms

I have a form, and i want to post it to mysql, without submit. I found out to post the values with ajax on every values. If i click on the one text field it inserts a new row to mysql and if i move to the next field it updates the mysql with my values. Is it possible?

My form:

```
 <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" name="name">
 <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" name="level">
 <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" name="pass"> 
 <input type="text" maxlength="50" size="50" value="" name="date">
```

etc.

Comment: First insert, then update :)

Comment: You sure you to update your database after each keyup? I recommand the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) function. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/NHffH/)

Comment: What happens when someone half enters a record then navigates away from the page?  You seem to be opening yourself up for a lot of invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden input with the id and give it no value, then on the submit on every keyup event, and if the id field is empty run an insert query and return the id, and update the id field with the value. If the value is not empty, run an update query with the form data. I provided an example using jQuery, but you could do the same thing without it. Ajax is just much easier with jQuery or any other library.

```
<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value=''/>


$('input').keyup(function(){
  var data = $('#myform').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    data:data,
    url:'...',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(response){
       var id = response.id;
       if(typeof(id) != 'undefined'){
          $('#id').val(id);
       }
    }
  });
});
```